# Beamer block environment without title

Tags: beamer, environments

Is it possible to create a customised beamer block environment that only has a body and not a title?

For example, I wish to typeset the following quote within a coloured block so that it stands out but I have no need for the block's title. I just want the quote to be superimposed on a coloured, rounded, and shadowed box.

```
\begin{example}
{\large ``To be, or not to be: that is the question.''}
\vskip5mm
\hspace*\fill{\small--- William Shakespeare, Hamlet}
\end{example}
```

If not, are there suggestions for how to do this in another package, like tikz?

Comment: Just leave the title empty...

Comment: Certainly when I've done this, it's been by leaving the title empty as Seamus says.  This *might* be theme-dependent so if it doesn't work, be sure to say which themes you are using.

Comment: Leaving the title empty works on an ordinary block but not an example block (which always has the title "Example"). So my next step would be to change the colour of the body section, to something similar to the example block for my theme. In the beamer user guide there are instructions for changing the font colour, is it possible to change the background colour.

Comment: Forgot to add, the problem with using an ordinary block is that the block's body background colour is light grey for the theme I am using (Warsaw) and I would prefer the light green of the example block. Perhaps I should edit the question to make this clearer?

Comment: @Steve: Those comments would have been helpful to have had in the question!  They make it easier to see exactly where the problem lies and so easier to find an answer (as Gonzalo has now done for you).  Neither Seamus nor I twigged that the `example` block puts "Example" in its title (had either of us actually compiled some code we would have seen it!).  Incidentally, it *is* possible to change background colours in beamer.  The manual has the details, and if that's not clear then ask a fresh question about it.

Comment: @Andrew Stacey: Noted, I need to make my questions clearer. I did discover how to change background colours from percusse's answer.

Comment: @Steve: learning how to ask a good question is a gradual process (and not one I've learnt yet)!  And it's often easier to see what's missing in other's questions than one's own; so my comment certainly isn't intended as criticism, but to help you next time.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You could use an `exampleblock` environment with empty title:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{exampleblock}{}
  {\large ``To be, or not to be: that is the question.''}
  \vskip5mm
  \hspace*\fill{\small--- William Shakespeare, Hamlet}
\end{exampleblock}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this specifically answers the question! For a more general solution see that given by percusse below.

Comment: You don't actually need the Warsaw theme for that.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I want block title color without the title.

Answer (score 25):

A simple solution, as given in the Beamer manual p.124, might be customizing the following code to your needs.

```
\setbeamercolor{postit}{fg=black,bg=yellow}
\begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=1em,wd=5cm]{postit}
Place me somewhere!
\end{beamercolorbox}
```

Also you can make it look like a block without its title.

Comment: Thanks, this is also great answer as it offers a general solution to the problem of framing text in beamer.

I am able to recreate Gonzalo's solution with the following code:
    `\setbeamercolor{postit}{fg=black,bg=example text.fg!75!black!10!bg}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\textwidth,rounded=true,shadow=true]{postit}
    Quote here.
   \end{beamercolorbox}`

Comment: Well, I just copied it from the manual but you are a quick study, good luck. :)

Answer (score 23):

Another working quick-fix in cases where `\begin{block}{}` causes some ugliness at the top of the block, you can use negative vertical space as the block title:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Copenhagen}

\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[default]

\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{frame}

\begin{block}{abc}
abcabc
\end{block}

\begin{block}{}
defdef
\end{block}

\begin{block}{\vspace*{-3ex}}
ghighi
\end{block}

\end{frame}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\end{document}
```

Comment: The accepted solution didn't work for me. This one did.

Comment: Thanks for this nice little trick!

Comment: Cool! Following worked for me with IEEEeqnarray environment

\begin{block}{}\vspace*{-3ex}
\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}
 a^2=b^2+c^2
 \label{a} 
\end{IEEEeqnarray}
\end{block}

Answer (score 10):

This is just a remark regarding percusses solution and Steve's usage, but i can't add a comment, because their discussion has been over too long ago. Instead of creating a new `beamer color` with approximately the same colors as the `block body example` color, it would be wiser to just use the predefined color if one intents to create a block with the same appearance:

```
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\textwidth,rounded=true,shadow=true]{block body example}
   Quote here.
\end{beamercolorbox}
```

Answer (score 4):

My solution would be to change the `block begin` template. It's default is defined in `beamerinnerthemedefault.sty` as

```
\defbeamertemplate*{block begin}{default}
{
  \par\vskip\medskipamount%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep*=.75ex]{block title}
    \usebeamerfont*{block title}\insertblocktitle%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  {\parskip0pt\par}%
  \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block title}
  {}
  {\ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body}{}{\nointerlineskip\vskip-0.5pt}}%
  \usebeamerfont{block body}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep*=.75ex,vmode]{block body}%
    \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body}{\vskip-.25ex}{\vskip-.75ex}\vbox{}%
}
```

In your document you can create an additional option for `block begin` with has no title by deleting the first few lines of the definition:

```
%create template for block without title
\defbeamertemplate{block begin}{notitle}
{
  \usebeamerfont{block body}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep*=.75ex,vmode]{block body}%
    \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body}{\vskip-.25ex}{\vskip-.75ex}\vbox{}%
}
```

Now you can turn off the title bar with `\setbeamertemplate{block begin}[notitle]` and turn it back on with `\setbeamertemplate{block begin}[default]`.

Of course this is only true if you use a `inner theme` which uses `\setbeamertemplate{block begin}[default]`. If your `inner theme` uses another option for `block begin`, you need to make a copy of that and change it accordingly. `rounded` for example (used by `inner theme` `rounded`) is defined in `beamerauxtemplates.sty`. Also the command to turn titles back on would need to be copied from your theme, in that case from `beamerinnerthemerounded.sty`.